# How can I reference another class property in a class method?

Tags: javascript, es6-class

I created this class User:

```
class User {
    constructor(socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
        this.socket.on('disconnect', this.onDisconnect);
        this.room = 'test';
    }

    onDisconnect () {
        console.log('socket disconnected');
        console.log(this);
    }
}
```

It has a method onDisconnect and a property room.

In the onDisconnect method `this` is the socket object. How can I reference other class properties? Specifically `this.room`

Comment: Create `onDisconnect()` using the arrow function syntax: `onDisconnect = () => { ... }`

Comment: `this.socket.on('disconnect', (...args) => this.onDisconnect(...args));`

Answer (score 0):

You can use function bind method like

```
this.socket.on('disconnect', this.onDisconnect.bind(socket));
```